# Does wso2 emm support Windows PC?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

Good day

I am looking to use the wso2 emm on windows devices.

From the documentation, it said "EMM supports devices running on Windows 8.1." And the software is "WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager" and contains "Mobile Device Management (MDM)".

My question is whether the wso2 emm can manage Windows PC. I've tried to enroll on both Windows 8 PC and Windows 10 PC. But I failed.

Can it only support Windows 8.1?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

up to now wso2 EMM2.0.1 supports only windows 8.1 mobile devices.But windows10 will enable Windows PC and any platform support. Wso2 EMM  will give these support in future release.